# Approximation for an expectation expression

Tags: pr.probability, linear-algebra, inequalities, expectation

Let $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{C}^M$ is an unknown distributed random vector (certainly not gaussian), and matrix $\mathbf{A}\in \mathbb{C}^{M \times M}$ which is fix (known). Also, assume we know the covariance of $\mathbf{x}$ or $\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^{\mathrm H}]$.  Now, I'm looking for any approximation or bound for the following expression in terms of $\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^{\mathrm H}]$;

$\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^{\mathrm H} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^{\mathrm H}]$

Comment: Do you have a response to the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such approximation or bound. E.g., suppose that $M=1$, $\mathbf A=[1]$, and $\mathbf x$ is a (random $1\times1$ matrix whose only entry is) a real-valued random variable with pdf $p$ given by the formula
$$p(x)=cx^{-4}\,1(|x|>a)$$
for real $x$, where $a:=1/\sqrt3$ and $c:=a/2$.
Then $\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^{\mathrm H}]=[1]$, but
$\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^{\mathrm H} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^{\mathrm H}]=[\infty]$.